# I stored values in Multi Dimensional Array. When printing the values, it's printing the second iteration values and first iteration is being replaced

Tags: bash, unix

This block of code is looping through a file and loading each word into a multi dimensional array.

```
lcv=0
declare -A db
while read line;
do
  lcv1=0
  echo $line
  for i in $line;
  do
    db[$lcv,$lcv1]=$i
    echo $lcv,$lcv1,${db[$lcv,$lcv1]};
    #echo ${db[$lcv]}
    ((++lcv1))
  done
  ((++lcv))
done < data.txt # File Contains records of 4 fields.
echo ${db[0,1]}
echo ${db[0,0]}
```

Comment: @codeforester This looks mostly like using complex indices in an associative array to get functionality similar to multidimensional arrays, but they're not really. Rocky, you might want to tag this [tag:bash] as the POSIX shell has not arrays at all.

Comment: Please post output of `declare -p db`!

Comment: Can you please add the content of `data.txt` to your question?

Comment: @codeforester Watch out with fixing obvious mistakes in the code of questions: [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) For example, removing semicolons seems to be matter of taste to me and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Point noted.  Thanks.  Sorry, @Rocky.

Comment: $ declare -p db
-bash: declare: db: not found

Comment: @Rocky, the request is for `declare -p db` *after your script has populated `db`*.

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing issues identified there before asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

#### Little pseudo 2D array using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

I just re-use your algorithm, whiping all `echo` and useless steps.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset x y db
y=0
declare -A db
while read line ;do
    for i in $line ;do
        db[$((x++)),$y]=$i
    done
    ((y++))
    x=0
  done <<<$'0 1 2 3\n4 5 6 7\n8 9 a b\nc d e f'
```

Now if you

```
declare -p db x y
```

bash will print:

```
declare -A db='([0,0]="0" [0,1]="4" [0,2]="8" [0,3]="c" [3,3]="f" [3,2]="b" [3,1]="7" [3,0]="3" [2,2]="a" [2,3]="e" [2,0]="2" [2,1]="6" [1,1]="5" [1,0]="1" [1,3]="d" [1,2]="9" )'
declare -- x="0"
declare -- y="4"
```

At this point, I just wanna purpose to change 9th line: `((y++))` by `((y++,maxx=maxx>x?maxx:x))`. This will populate `maxx` (to `4` in this sample)

Then inverting the array:

```
for i in {0..4};do           # this syntax is nice, but don't support variables
    for((j=0;j<y;j++)){      # this syntaxe could use variables
        echo -n ${db[$i,$j]}\ 
    }
    echo
done
```

will print:

```
0 4 8 c 
1 5 9 d 
2 6 a e 
3 7 b f
```

Comment: Your internal line: `db[$((x++)),$y]=$i` increments `x`, while the OP user was incrementing what you call `y` (`lcv1`). This switch rows and columns. This is not equivalent to the OP problem.

Comment: @sorontar I've re-used OP's algo, replacing` lcv` by `y`, but i'ts same algorythm for popuiating db. And yes, as a demo for this array, second part switch row and columns,

Comment: What I meant to say is that you did `db[$((x++)),$y]=$i` while the OP did `db[$y,$((x++))]=$i`.

Comment: @sorontar Oh yes! But who care? Anyway, [tag:bash] don't: There is no ordering method in an *associative array*.

Answer (score 1):

If the data.txt contains this:

```
$ cat data.txt
l0val0 l0val1 l0val2 l0val3
l1val0 l1val1 l1val2 l1val3
l2val0 l2val1 l2val2 l2val3
l3val0 l3val1 l3val2 l3val3
l4val0 l4val1 l4val2 l4val3
l5val0 l5val1 l5val2 l5val3
```

Your program produce this:

```
$ ./script
l0val0 l0val1 l0val2 l0val3
0,0,l0val0
0,1,l0val1
0,2,l0val2
0,3,l0val3
l1val0 l1val1 l1val2 l1val3
1,0,l1val0
1,1,l1val1
1,2,l1val2
1,3,l1val3
l2val0 l2val1 l2val2 l2val3
2,0,l2val0
2,1,l2val1
2,2,l2val2
2,3,l2val3
l3val0 l3val1 l3val2 l3val3
3,0,l3val0
3,1,l3val1
3,2,l3val2
3,3,l3val3
l4val0 l4val1 l4val2 l4val3
4,0,l4val0
4,1,l4val1
4,2,l4val2
4,3,l4val3
l5val0 l5val1 l5val2 l5val3
5,0,l5val0
5,1,l5val1
5,2,l5val2
5,3,l5val3
l0val1
l0val0
```

That goes to show that the value of `$lcv` selects each row (line), and the value of `$lcv1` selects each word (record) divided on spaces or tabs.

It is working correctly from what I can see.

If we add this lines at the end of the script:

```
echo "end of first script"
for i in {0..5}; do
    for j in {0..3}; do
    printf 'db[%s,%s]=%s  ' "$i" "$j" "${db[$i,$j]}"
    done
    echo
done

echo
declare -p db
```

We will get this output:

```
end of first script
db[0,0]=l0val0  db[0,1]=l0val1  db[0,2]=l0val2  db[0,3]=l0val3  
db[1,0]=l1val0  db[1,1]=l1val1  db[1,2]=l1val2  db[1,3]=l1val3  
db[2,0]=l2val0  db[2,1]=l2val1  db[2,2]=l2val2  db[2,3]=l2val3  
db[3,0]=l3val0  db[3,1]=l3val1  db[3,2]=l3val2  db[3,3]=l3val3  
db[4,0]=l4val0  db[4,1]=l4val1  db[4,2]=l4val2  db[4,3]=l4val3  
db[5,0]=l5val0  db[5,1]=l5val1  db[5,2]=l5val2  db[5,3]=l5val3  
declare -A db=([1,1]="l1val1" [1,0]="l1val0" [1,3]="l1val3" [1,2]="l1val2" [0,0]="l0val0" [0,1]="l0val1" [0,2]="l0val2" [0,3]="l0val3" [5,1]="l5val1" [5,0]="l5val0" [5,3]="l5val3" [5,2]="l5val2" [3,3]="l3val3" [3,2]="l3val2" [3,1]="l3val1" [3,0]="l3val0" [2,2]="l2val2" [2,3]="l2val3" [2,0]="l2val0" [2,1]="l2val1" [4,0]="l4val0" [4,1]="l4val1" [4,2]="l4val2" [4,3]="l4val3" )
```

Now, the question is: What do you think that is wrong?.